# How do I organize my data for time series cluster analysis using the dtwclust package?

Tags: r, time-series, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to do a hierarchical cluster dendrogram of time series in R using the dtwclust package. For my test dataset I have 4 columns with unequal lengths. the dtwclust package offers a way to equalize the lengths using a reinterpolate function. However I get this error when I try to use it with the following code

```
data <- reinterpolate(fshdtw, new.length = max(lengths(fshdtw)))
```

Error in check_consistency(x, "ts") : There are missing values in the series. This makes me think (I could be wrong) that the data table is not organized properly. Can anyone suggest how to 1. read in the data (I just imported it using RStudio) or any other way to resolve this issue. PS: I tried the analysis using the data provided in the package and it worked as advertised. Thanks in advance!
The data file is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/dih39ji0zop9xa0/fshdtw.txt?dl=0